# Safari css stops working on larger screen

Tags: css, safari

I have inherited a web page with a large amount of CSS.

I'm working on a Mac Book Pro laptop connected to a 29" monitor.

In Safari on the laptop screen the page and the css work as expected.

If I drag the Safari window on to the monitor the CSS stops working.

I'm completely baffled. What could be causing this in the CSS, what should I look for.

Comment: It stops working entirely? Are you resizing the window at all? Are there any @media lines in your CSS?

Comment: The css is split into different files and then using grunt to concate it. There are media lines in the css but it only happens in Safari

Comment: @ttmt Did you ever find a solution? I'm having this exact issue and its driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had a media query like which appeared half-way in the minimized CSS:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), only screen and (min-resolution: 200dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

This should be valid as far as I can see, but yet when Safari encountered it it just seemed to crash internally and not parse anything afterwards.

Removing the media query prevented the problem.